# How do I use a batch copy to update files?

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste

I need help writing a batch file to update templates on a database. Basically, all our clients have their own folder, with multiple templates inside.  Due to the computer illiteracy of my office (*sigh*), there's no real better way to fix this. However, I need a way to update those templates in a batch. For instance

```
\\SERVER\New Client Template Folder\Correspondence\Transmittal Letter.WPD
```

is updated. I then need to copy it to:

```
\\SERVER\Client Files\Client 1\Correspondence;
\\SERVER\Client Files\Client 2\Correspondence;
```

...etc. Essentially, I need to copy to `\\SERVER\Client Files\\*\\`, and I need to make it a batch file that I can train someone else to use whenever I leave this job. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The new versions of Windows (7 and 2008 Server R2) have the robust file copy tool (`robocopy`).  This can be installed on XP and 2003 also be installed using the [Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).  Essentially, `robocopy` gives you a command-line directory mirroring tool that could help you accomplish what you're trying to do.  Simply place `robocopy` commands into a batch file  (`/MIR` = mirror directory contents `/XJ` = ignore junctions) :

```
robocopy <source_dir> <destination_dir> /MIR /XJ
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate which operating system you are working under. Let me guess its windows. My DOS BAT file knowledge is limited, but you
could try creating a BAT file with something like:

```
set Src="\\SERVER\New Client Template Folder\Correspondence\Transmittal Letter.WPD"
set DestA="\\SERVER\Client Files\
set DestB=\Correspondence;"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (distribution.txt) DO copy %Src% %DestA%%%i%DestB%
```

and then create a `distribution.txt` file like:

```
Client 1
Client 2
```

Running this BAT file will read the `distribution.txt` file and issue a copy command for each line in it. As follows:

```
COPY "\\SERVER\New Client Template Folder\Correspondence\Transmittal Letter.WPD" "\\SERVER\Client Files\Client 1\Correspondence;"
COPY "\\SERVER\New Client Template Folder\Correspondence\Transmittal Letter.WPD" "\\SERVER\Client Files\Client 2\Correspondence;"
```

But there must be a better way!!!!

You can get more help on the `FOR` command by typing `help for` at the DOS prompt.

If you don't like the idea of having to build/maintain the `distribution.txt` file, you could play with using `DIR /A:D /B "\\SERVER\Client Files\*"` to drop a directory listing into a temporary file, then use it as input to the `FOR` loop.